# popup confirm how to know OK clicked in ionic 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework

I want to know and trigger the `OK` button on popup alert in my apps, and this is my code:

```
 $scope.showAlert = function (msg) {
    $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: msg.title,
      template: msg.message,
      okText: 'Baik',
      okType: 'button-positive' ,

    })
  }
$scope.showAlert({
          title: "Update",
          message: "Silahkan Update terlebih dahulu di playstore",
          onTap: function(e) {
            return $window.open('https://google.com', '_self') || true
          }
        });
```

so all I want is if I click the `OK` button, it is redirect to an external URL.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon at the end.  return $window.open('https://google.com', '_self') || true;

Comment: it doesnt matter